# Terms and conditions without content

Tags: checkout, terms-and-conditions

Is it possible to make the terms and conditions on checkout page before each process payment button as html? Instead of default magento terms and conditions I want it to be an html like that with no pop-up window:

```
<p>By placing your order, you agree to our <a href="">Terms & Conditions</a> and <a href="">Privacy Policy</a></p>
```

Comment: Yes you can do this one.

Comment: How to do that?